# Batch Sctiping Tokens

Tags: batch-file

I have the following issue. I am reading fields from a Database. These fields are not all mandatory. Ergo, not all of them are filled in. The issue I am having is with Batch (ms dos) and the Tokens function.

Let me give you an example:
The fields in question are as follows: (example)

```
First Name: John
Last Name: Smith
Address: 123 Fake Street
Postal Code: 45612
Company: SomeCo
Department: Accounting
Floor: 4
Phone: 123-555-5555
Mobile: 123-555-5556
```

When I run this code:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-9, delims=," %%a in (info_file.txt) DO echo %%a, %%b, %%c, %%d, %%e, %%f, %%g, %%h, %%i
```

The output would look like this:

```
%%a= John
%%b= Smith
%%c= 123 Fake Street
%%d= 45612
%%e= SomeCo
%%f= Accounting
%%g= 4
%%h= 123-555-5555
%%i= 123-555-5556
```

Everything is great. I get all the echoes correctly displayed. BUT! If any of those fields are missing, for example:

```
First Name: John
Last Name: Smith
Address: 123 Fake Street
Postal Code: <missing info; consider this line blank>
Company: SomeCo
Department:  <missing info; consider this line blank>
Floor:  4
Phone: 123-555-5555
Mobile: 123-555-5556
```

My output would look like this:

```
%%a= John
%%b= Smith
%%c= 123 Fake Street
%%d= SomeCo
%%e= 4
%%f= 123-555-5555
%%g= 123-555-5556
%%h= <not used; Because there is not enough lines available>
%%i= <not used; Because there is not enough lines available>
```

You can see how this can lead to frustration.
My question is: How can I make sure that all the `%%<variables>` always align, even when the information in that space is blank?

Comment: Can you post the actual file? It looks to me like it doesn't match. The batch command indicates a comma-separated file.

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is that your sample text does not fit to your code.
Your code splits a string at commas, but your sample uses only line feeds.

I assume, that you have a CSV.

Then you only need to replace each , with ,# because then no field will be empty, and later remove the first char.

```
Set line=#!line:,=,#!
```

Comment: Not as comprehensive as william-bettridge-radford's answer, but the same general idea and sooner too. +1 for the right direction (and because batch questions are undervalued in general).

Answer (score 2):

Another language such as python with a CSV library is probably best.

If you really want batch you could append another character temporarily to each section.
Such as appending and removing an underscore to the end of each section.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%z in (test.csv) do (
    set line=%%z
    rem append underscores
    set line=!line:,=_,!_
    for /f "tokens=1-9 delims=," %%a in ("!line!") do (
        call :remove_underscore arg1 "%%a"
        call :remove_underscore arg2 "%%b"
        call :remove_underscore arg3 "%%c"
        call :remove_underscore arg4 "%%d"
        echo arg1: '!arg1!'
        echo arg2: '!arg2!'
        echo arg3: '!arg3!'
        echo arg4: '!arg4!'
    )
    echo new line
    echo.
)
exit /b 0

:remove_underscore rval input_string
    set input_string=%~2
    set %1=%input_string:~0,-1%
    exit /b 0
```

Comment: +1, but solution would be better (safer) if used delayed expansion to remove underscore. It is also significantly faster to do everything within the loop without CALL: `set "arg1=%%a"&set "arg1=!arg1:~0,-1!"`

Answer (score 1):

The Batch file below take the ideas stated by jeb and William and collect they in a whole program that really works. This program is not restricted by the number of fields in the file nor the position of the missing fields that is required when `"tokens=1-..."` FOR option is used. Instead, it use a list of variable names that describe file fields so the program load the values *in the variables* (not in FOR tokens). This way, it is very easy to change the number of fields, the position of a particular field or any other modification in the file with just a change in the list of variables.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define names for variables (with NO spaces) in a comma-separated list
set fields=FirstName,LastName,Address,PostalCode,Company,Departament,Floor,Phone,Mobile
rem Previous list may also be read from the first line (header) of a DataBase file

rem Separate the list in an array of variable names
set i=0
for %%a in (%fields%) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set name[!i!]=%%a
)
set numFields=%i%

rem Process the file
for /F "delims=" %%a in (info_file.txt) do (
   set line=%%a
   rem Replace spaces by Ascii-128 (to avoid split values that may have spaces)
   set line=!line: =Ç!
   rem Insert any char. at beginning of each field, and separate fields with spaces
   set i=0
   for %%b in (X!line:^,^= X!) do (
      set field=%%b
      rem Recover spaces in this field, if any
      set field=!field:Ç= !
      rem And assign this field to corresponding variable (removing first character)
      set /A i+=1
      for %%i in (!i!) do set !name[%%i]!=!field:~1!
   )

   rem At this point all variables have the values of current record.
   rem They may be accessed explicitly:
   echo/
   echo Record of !FirstName! !LastName!
   rem ... or implicilty via the NAME array:
   for /L %%i in (3,1,%numFields%) do (
      for %%b in (!name[%%i]!) do echo    %%b: !%%b!
   )
)
```

info_file.txt:

```
John,Smith,123 Fake Street,45612,SomeCo,Accounting,4,123-555-5555,123-555-5556
Jane,Doe,123 Fake Street,,SomeCo,,4,123-555-5555,123-555-5556
```

Output:

```
Record of John Smith
   Address: 123 Fake Street
   PostalCode: 45612
   Company: SomeCo
   Departament: Accounting
   Floor: 4
   Phone: 123-555-5555
   Mobile: 123-555-5556

Record of Jane Doe
   Address: 123 Fake Street
   PostalCode:
   Company: SomeCo
   Departament:
   Floor: 4
   Phone: 123-555-5555
   Mobile: 123-555-5556
```

Antonio

Comment: You protect space, but you should also protect `;` `=` and tab. Although tab is less likely to be an issue. Also, values containing `*` or `?` will be corrupted. The `?` can be protected, but there is no good way to replace `*` with batch, so I don't see how it can be protected.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will try your code out Aacini in a few days. what is that C character in: set line=!line: =Ç! <--?

Comment: As the previous REM line indicate, it is Ascii character # 128. You may use any other character _that does not appear in the file_, but in this case be sure to use the same character six lines below.